# float() argument must be string or a number, not 'Equality'

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sp
from sympy import *
t = Symbol('t')
u = sp.Function('u')(t-1)
U = sp.Function('u')(t)
from sympy.abc import k
from sympy.abc import t
from sympy.abc import r
de = Eq(U, sp.E**(r*((1-u)/k))*u) 

def Ricker(k,t):
  if t > 0:
    return (de)
  else:
    None 

u = 2

k = 0.75

r = 0.5

tf = 50

uRecord = np.array([]) 
for t in range(tf + 1):
  uRecord = np.append( uRecord, u )
  u = Ricker(k,t)

tvals = np.arange(tf+1)
plt.plot(tvals, uRecord, '-', color='blue')
plt.xlabel(r"$t$", fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel(r"$u_t$", fontsize=14)
plt.title(r"$k=0.75, u_0 =0.25$", fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

I have code this code trying to plot ricker model from the de above, I get error on line
plt.plot(tvals, uRecord, '-', color='blue')
not sure why im getting an error, all help is appretiated

Comment: `Eq(U, sp.E**(r*((1-u)/k))*u)` isn't a number.

Comment: I made the equation and defined the variables in the code, is there something i did wrong with that?

Comment: Sympy is a symbolic algebra package, it doesn't actual evaluate equations.

Comment: what would you recommend i change so the equation plots properly. thx for the help btw

Comment: See https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html